# LaTeX3: {#1} or { #1 }

Tags: latex3

[l3styleguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) reads

> With the exception of simple runs of parameter ({#1}, #1#2, etc.), everything should
> be divided up using spaces to make the code more readable.

However, [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) shows examples both, `{#1}` and `{ #1 }`.

So, I am a bit puzzled. What the preferred way? Did it change over time?

Comment: since it makes no difference and the syntax has been in use by different people over a 30 year period some syle differences may have slipped in:-)

Comment: The preferred way is the way you think the code is more readable. Not everyone thinks that spaces achieve that goal.

Comment: Personally I hate those spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The style guide tries to codify 'common' practice by the team. As mentioned in comments, on balance `{#1}` felt more 'readable' than `{ #1 }` in most cases, whereas `{ \some_funct:N \l_some_var }` seemed preferable. It's not *universally* applied, but is the most common formatting choice so is what is recommended.

Comment: Thanks. interface3.pdf contains `{#1}` 21 times  and `{ #1 }` 15 times . This means the former is "most common", but only by a small margin.

Comment: @mhchem Remember there are the cases of `{#2}` and so on - see e.g. the definition for `\use_i:nnn`.

Comment: Also, you have to remember that say `{ #1 : #2 }` or `{ #2 #1 }` doesn't 'count' (the style guide here is specifically about parameter values given with nothing else and in order).

Comment: I did only count the verbatim occurrences of `{#1}` and `{ #1 }` in the official documentation document interface3.pdf.